# Force a maximum time to download image from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I'm trying to implement a method which tries to make a few attempts to download an image from url. To do so, I'm using requests lib. An example of my code is:

```
while attempts < nmr_attempts:
        try:
            attempts += 1
            response = requests.get(self.basis_url, params=query_params, timeout=response_timeout)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Each attempt can't spend more than "response_timeout" making the request. However It seems that the timeout variable is not doing anything since it does not respect the times given by myself.

How can I limit the max blocking time at response.get() call.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value you set for response_timeout?

Comment: The value is 1.5 seconds. But if i specify 0.1 seconds the time of response its exactly the same. What I want is throw an exception whenever the the timeout is reached. Independently, if the request is completed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try following (get rid of try-except block) and see if it helps? **except Exception** is probably suppressing the exception that **requests.get** throws.

```
while attempts < nmr_attempts:
    response = requests.get(self.basis_url, params=query_params, timeout=response_timeout)
```

Or with your original code, you can catch **requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout** exception. Such as:

```
while attempts < nmr_attempts:
    try:
        attempts += 1
        response = requests.get(self.basis_url, params=query_params, timeout=response_timeout)
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as e:
        do_something()
```

Comment: But I want to catch the exception in case of timeout. I'll try to explain better: Imagine that you're making requests to an invalid URL. What I want is don't wait more than response timeout until receive the response from server. In my case this response brings an image in it content.

Comment: @MiguelAndrade I updated my answer. You can catch requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout instead of the generic Exception.

Comment: It throws me another exceptions. I catch the requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout but It also does not work. I've printend the time difference between the time that the request is made and the exception is throwed up and it is always 1 second. Independently of timeout.